# Push websocket notification with Faye from Observer in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, faye

I'm trying to build a simple websocket notification system using rails observers gem and faye. The problem is that I can't publish with faye from the observer.

First I created the observer:

```
class ScoreObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

     def after_save(score)
       @notification = Notification.new(user_id: '2', content: '¡rororscoreeeeeeeeeeeeee!')
       if @notification.save
          client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')
          client.publish("/messages/new", {
            'title' => 'testitle',
            'content' => 'testcontent'
            })
       end      
     end

end
```

As you can see it 'observes' the scores model and insert a record in the notifications table. After that I want it to push a notification with faye using pubilsh.

Then in the client side I run the subscribe script

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
  faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
    alert('it works')
  });
});
```

And it doesn't work. The observer is aware of the action and makes the record save correctly but the client doesn't receive any push from the websocket.

I've tested the subscription with a simple broadcast and it works so it seems that is the observer part which is failling. Websockets are up and listening

Do you have any clue of what could be wrong ?

I was looking for an alternative just in case this approach is wrong, and I thought about render a script from the observer and broadcast/publish from a .js file, since all the tuts do it from a script. But I'm having some trouble with this approach too, I can't render a script from the observer in respond_to since the model extends from Observer and not from Base and doesn't have the method.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the Faye server mounted? In the observer you're connecting the client to `http://localhost:3000/faye` while in the JavaScript you're connecting to `http://localhost:9292/faye`. Both clients will need to connect to the same server.

Comment: Hi @BartJedrocha thanks to point it out, the port is 9292. I just copied it wrong in the question. I've edited it.

Comment: And Faye is running? Are you seeing the requests in the console? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: Faye is running, I can see the "Started POST "/faye" for 127.0.0.1 at ... " log line printing each second in the console and the app it's not throwing any error. @BartJedrocha

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're not running the client within EventMachine as described [here](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/clients.html). Another option is to include `rest-client` and simply post using rest client. Please look [here](https://gist.github.com/bjedrocha/8da487ed92fb66a3459a)

Comment: I've just found a routes error, it's weird because when I google it the only reference is in the hub of 'faye-rails' [link](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails/issues/31)  which I'm not using, I'm with 'faye'